# The login form returns error even if the password and username are correct

Tags: java

The login form below returns error even if the password and username are correct:

```
login.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String us = user.getText().toLowerCase();
            char[] passs = pasword.getPassword();

            String myuser = "a";
            String mypass = "b";
            if(us.equals(myuser) && String.valueOf(passs).equals(mypass)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "correct");

            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "incorrect");

            }
    }});
```

Comment: Print things surrounded by `*` and you'll spot the difference.

Comment: may be space around them causing an issue, trim and compare....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Herr `passs.equals(mypass)` you compare an char[] with a string.

You have to convert the char[] to a string :

```
String.valueOf(passs).equals(mypass)
```

Comment: i did what u said but still the problem is there...it gives me incorrect login even if the password and username are correct

Comment: @abdulazizibrahim What is the content of passs?

Comment: am entering username as a and password as b

Comment: @abdulazizibrahim please use a debugger. to see what the content of pass and us is.

Answer (score 2):

### The problem

You are comparing `passs`, which is a `char[]` with `mypass` which is a `String`. As there is no `.equals()` method on `char[]`, the one used will be the one from `Object`:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

And this will return `false`, as `passs` and `mypass` are not the same object.

### How to solve it

As said by @Jens, you can convert the `char[]` to a `String`:

```
String.valueOf(passs).equals(mypass)
```

or you can convert the `String` to a `char[]` and compare it to the other one:

```
Arrays.equals(passs, mypass.toCharArray())
```

Comment: i did what u said but still the problem is there...it gives me incorrect login even if the password and username are correct